# Create new array from key list in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want a quick easy way to copy an array but the ability to specify which keys in the array I want to copy.

I can easily write a function for this, but I'm wondering if there's a PHP function that does this already. Something like the `array_from_keys()` function below.

```
$sizes = array('small' => '10px', 'medium' => '12px', 'large' => '13px');

$chosen = array_from_keys($sizes, 'small', 'large');

// $chosen = array('small' => '10px', 'large' => '13px');
```

Answer (score 9):

There's a native function in PHP that allows such manipulations, i.e.  `array_intersect_key`, however you will have to modify your syntax a little bit.

```
 <?php
      $sizes = array('small' => '10px', 'medium' => '12px', 'large' => '13px');
      $selected = array_fill_keys(array('small', 'large'), null); 
      $result = array_intersect_key($sizes, $selected);
 ?>
```

$result will contain:

```
    Array (
        [small] => 10px
        [large] => 13px
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for that.

A slightly better way to build the array:
$selected = array_fill_keys('small', 'large', null);

Although it's still not very elegant. Still worth writing that 'array_from_keys' function I think.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a function for this as far as I know. The easiest way would be to do something like this I think:

```
$chosen = array_intersect_key($sizes, array_flip(array('small', 'large')));
```

Or as you say you can easily write a function:

```
function array_from_keys() {
    $params = func_get_args();
    $array = array_shift($params);
    return array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($params));
}

$chosen = array_from_keys($sizes, 'small', 'large');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach:

```
$sizes = array('small' => '10px', 'medium' => '12px', 'large' => '13px');
$chosen = array("small", "large");
$new = array();

foreach ($chosen as $key)
  $new[$key] = $sizes[$key];
```