# Remove elements from an associative array of objects using a flat, whitelist array

Tags: php, arrays, key, whitelist, array-intersect

I need to filter an array of objects using a flat array of whitelisted values.

```
$objects = [
    3 => (object) ['tid' => 3],
    12 => (object) ['tid' => 12],
    9 => (object) ['tid' => 9],
];

$whitelist = [3, 4, 9, 11];
```

The whitelist doesn't contain 12, so that object should be removed.

Desired output:

```
[
    3 => (object) ['tid' => 3],
    9 => (object) ['tid' => 9],
]
```

Comment: Dupe: [Create new array from key list in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/938016/2943403)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some clean up it was pretty clear what I needed, and this little bit sorts it out:

```
foreach ($second_array as $foo) {
  if (!in_array($foo->tid, $first_array)) {
    unset($second_array[$foo->tid]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this:

```
$keys = array_map(function($val) { return $val['value']; }, $first);
$result = array_intersect_key(array_flip($keys), $second);
```

The [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) call will extract the *value* values from `$first` so that `$keys` is an array of these values. Then [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) is used to get the intersection of `$keys` (flipped to use the keys as values and vice versa) and the second array `$second`.

Comment: The question details have significantly changed since the posting of your answer, please consider updating this answer.

Answer (score 5):

For associative arrays it can be used simple key allow-list filter:

```
$arr = array('a' => 123, 'b' => 213, 'c' => 321); 
$allowed = array('b', 'c'); 

print_r(array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip($allowed)));
```

Will return:

```
Array 
( 
    [b] => 213 
    [c] => 321 
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to filter your array (by all keys that are contained in the other array), you may use the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php) function.

```
$first  = [3,4,9,11];
$second = [ 3 => 'A' , 9 => 'B' , 12 => 'C'];

$clean = array_filter($second, function($key)use($first){
            return in_array($key,$first);
          },
           ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

// $clean = [ 3 => 'A' , 9 => 'B'];
```

The `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` constant is the 3rd parameter of the function so that `$key`  is actually the key of the `$second` array in the callback. This can be adjusted:

> Flag determining what arguments are sent to callback (3rd argument):
>
> ```
> ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY - pass key as the only argument to callback instead of the value
> ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH - pass both value and key as arguments to callback instead of the value
> ```
>
> Default is 0 which will pass value as the only argument to callback
>   instead.

Comment: @Nic3500 your right, I improved my answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Use a callback in [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter)

If your first array really looks like that, you might want to alter it in a more usable one-dimensional array, so you use a simple `in_array` as part of your callback:

```
$values = array_map('reset',$array);
```

---

I only now see that the keys & object-ids are alike:

```
$result =  array_intersect_key($objectarray,array_flip(array_map('reset',$array)));
```

Comment: Exactly what I've been struggling with. "return $arr['value']" in the callback is what I expected to work.

Comment: PHP doesn't like calling `reset` on the objects. https://3v4l.org/JUX2S  The question details have been updated to better define the data being processed.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the `tid` column values in each object against the whitelist values, no flipping, column extraction, or iterated calls of `in_array()` are necessary.  Call `array_uintersect()` to compare the arrays of different depths.  `$a` and `$b` in the custom function can come from either input array, so try to access the object property first and if it doesn't exist, then it is safe to assume that the value comes from the flat, whitelist array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YdbK0))

```
$objects = [
    3 => (object) ['tid' => 3],
    12 => (object) ['tid' => 12],
    9 => (object) ['tid' => 9],
];

$whitelist = [3, 4, 9, 11];

var_export(
    array_uintersect($objects, $whitelist, fn($a, $b) => ($a->tid ?? $a) <=> ($b->tid ?? $b))
);
```

---

That said, the data in this question lends itself to faster computation by comparing the objectArray's keys against the whitelist array values.  In this context, the fastest approach will be to flip the whitelist and call `array_intersect_key()` which was demonstrated much earlier than this answer.